# Datepicker not appearing when an url alias is added

Tags: 7, javascript, uri

I've implemented a datepicker in a textfield on a basic page from Drupal. It works fine and the url shown is "http://....../drupal7/node/28".

If I add an url alias to the url, the datepicker doesn't appear. It only reappears if I remove the url alias.

Anyone know how to show the datepicker with an url alias?

The files used are:

jquery-1.10.2

jquery-ui.js

jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0):

I have [date_popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module under date enabled and any form field with date_popup type displays date picker for me:

```
$form['my_date'] = array(
      '#type' => 'date_popup',
      '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
      '#title' => t( 'My Date' ),
  );
```

It seems to work for me regardless of which url it is used on.